# Как сделать адаптивную кнопку со сложным фоном на CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, button

собственно вот на [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу понять, как можно сделать саморастягивающуюся кнопку с такими стрелками по бокам (пробовал сделать просто сплошные стрелки, но мне это не подходит, нужно с такой полоской по контуру), а также полоски вверху и снизу кнопки (к краю они исчезают, а в центре наиболее яркие

Comment: Просто стилями такое не сделать, необходимо картинку беграунд использовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать по такому принципу:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 60px;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQPcT.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 27px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyKbw.png) no-repeat left -10px top -6px;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 27px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyKbw.png) no-repeat right -12px top -6px;
}
```

```html
<div>la-la</div>
<div>ooo la-la!</div>
```

Полоски сверху и снизу можете добавить отдельно с помощью liner-gradient спозиционированные абсолютно.

Comment: как всегда, ответ на хорошем уровне